# Any numeric string except the string containing '000'

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

How to match all numbers except `000`. That is,

```
001234567502344001233400122300 is fine.
0123456750023440012334012230 is fine.
000123456750234400123340012230 is not fine.
001234567502344000123340012230 is not fine.
0012345675023440012334001223000 is not fine.
00123456750234400012334001223000 is not fine.
001002003004005006 is fine.
001 id fine
10 is fine.
01 is fine.
000 is not fine.
```

Should I use negative Lookaheads or the following technique:

```
/(()|()|())/g
```

Comment: any help will be appreciated.

Comment: E.g. `(?!000)[0-9]{3}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew; This is not a solution. I tried on https://regex101.com/. Check following string. The digits can be of any length not just 3 digits. Check this data "111111112223445567889
111111112221111111122234455678890
1111111122211111111222344556788900
11111111222111111112223445567889
11111111222000111111112223445567889
00011111111222111111112223445567889
11111111222111111112223445567889000
00011111111222111111112223445567889000
000"

Comment: Its matching 000. I want not to match any string of digits that dont contain string 000.

Comment: It sounds as if you want `^(?!000$)\d+$` (not equal to `000`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k4hGUv/1)) or `^(?!\d*000)\d+$` (not containing `000`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k4hGUv/2))

Comment: What does it mean *not working*? If you want to extract these chunks from larger text, use something like `\b(?!\d*000)\d+\b` (contains) or `\b(?!000\b)\d+\b` (equals)

Comment: Does any of these work as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew; yes indeed. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: Which one works for you?

Comment: ^(?!\d*000)\d+$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!\d*000)\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k4hGUv/2) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F!%5Cd*000)%5Cd%2B%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?!\d*000)` - right after start of string, there cannot be any 0+ digits followed with `000` substring
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Note that this is a less generic solution than the earlier solution. The other solution can be embedded in other patterns, whereas this one can't. In that situation, why not just use `!/000/`?

Comment: @ikegami; Ok but can you define generic. You mean this one can't be embedded or used with other regex patterns?

Comment: It can't be embedded in other patterns, so it's just a complicated way of saying `/^\d$/ && !/000/`

Comment: @BabarKamran My solution answers your question exactly. If you need to mach some other types of strings, please edit the question.

Comment: @ikegami It only contains what it should, there is nothing complex. Only a single lookahead compred to your tempered greedy token is a much more lightweight pattern.

Comment: There's no lookahead in `!/000/` (or `/^\d$/ && !/000/`)

Comment: @ikegami You have a tempered greedy token in `(?:(?!000).)*` and `(?:(?!000)\d)*`. TGT is a very resource consuming construct, and this is not necessary here.

Comment: I agree. That's why that's not the solution I gave. `!/000/` should be used.

Comment: It won't work with a plain text regex. The code solution is not what OP seeks.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
$string !~ /000/
```

Test:

```
$ perl -nle'printf "%s is %s\n", $_, !/000/ ? "fine" : "not fine"' <<'.'
001234567502344001233400122300
0123456750023440012334012230
000123456750234400123340012230
001234567502344000123340012230
0012345675023440012334001223000
00123456750234400012334001223000
001002003004005006
001
10
01
000
.
001234567502344001233400122300 is fine
0123456750023440012334012230 is fine
000123456750234400123340012230 is not fine
001234567502344000123340012230 is not fine
0012345675023440012334001223000 is not fine
00123456750234400012334001223000 is not fine
001002003004005006 is fine
001 is fine
10 is fine
01 is fine
000 is not fine
```

---

If this is suppose to be part of a larger pattern, that you want to make sure that each position isn't the start of `000`.

```
(?:(?!000).)*
```

For example,

```
/^(?:(?!000).)*\z/
```

For example,

```
my @safe_numbers = $string_with_multiple_numbers =~ /\b(?:(?!000)\d)*\b/g;
```

Comment: /?:(?!000).)*/mg is not excluding string that has 000. I saw it is matching only 0 and 00 so its matching all numbers except 000. And I want to exclude that whole string at a line.

Comment: You need to provide some form of anchoring, as I showed. `(?:(?!000).)*` on its own is useless as it can match zero characters. Like I said, `(?:(?!000).)*` is to be used as part of a larger pattern. I provided a simpler solution that doesn't need to be part of a larger pattern.